v3/teams/{teamId}/conversations returning 403 ServiceError Unknown
Seeing errors with code ServiceError and message Unknown when calling v3/teams/{teamId}/conversations API via Botbuilder SDK. Started a few hours ago - nothing has been changed in the bot's code. Tested it out with several teams and getting the same error for all of them.
This is the full error returned in our logs:
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503372270Z RestError: Unknown
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503390371Z at new RestError (/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:2480:28)
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503396371Z at /node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:3687:37
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503406972Z at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503428172Z code: 'ServiceError',
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503432773Z statusCode: 403,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503437073Z request: WebResource {
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503441573Z streamResponseBody: false,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503445973Z url: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/teams/{TEAM_ID_HERE}/conversations',
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503450473Z method: 'GET',
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503454773Z headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503459174Z body: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503463374Z query: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503467574Z formData: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503472074Z withCredentials: false,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503476374Z abortSignal: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503480574Z timeout: 0,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503484874Z onUploadProgress: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503489175Z onDownloadProgress: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503493475Z proxySettings: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503497675Z keepAlive: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503501875Z agentSettings: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503506175Z redirectLimit: undefined,
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503510475Z operationSpec: {
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503520876Z httpMethod: 'GET',
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503525176Z path: 'v3/teams/{teamId}/conversations',
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503529576Z urlParameters: [Array],
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503533776Z responses: [Object],
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503538076Z serializer: [Serializer]
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503542377Z }
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503546677Z },
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503550877Z response: {
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503555177Z body: '{"error":{"code":"ServiceError","message":"Unknown"}}',
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503560077Z headers: HttpHeaders { _headersMap: [Object] },
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503564677Z status: 403
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503568878Z },
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503573178Z body: undefined
2024-04-15T18:41:54.503577378Z }

We're unsure which method this ties back to as proactive posting to a teams channel is successful.

We've confirmed that the error is coming from the TeamsInfo.getTeamChannels method. We've confirmed this error is present with botbuilder v4.16.0 and botbuilder v4.22.2
